# Getting null datetime value from view to controller when i change CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, cultureinfo

net mvc, i have a controller which gets a datetime parameter from view using jquery datepicker and then i pass 
the value to the controller using json ,
it all works fine, except when i change language cultureInfo to German in my case, the value of datetime parameter is always null.

This is the controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetDetails(DateTime? from, DateTime? to)
    {
       //Do something..
    }
```

The model:

```
public class UsagesModel
   {
       public DateTime From
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime To
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The view in which data gets chosen and then pass to controller:

```
 <input type="text" id="from" value="@Model.From.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" class="datepicker" />

 <input type="text" id="to" value="@Model.To.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" class="datepicker" />
```

```
 $("#filter").click(function (e) {

   fromdate = $("#from").val();
   todate = $("#to").val();

 $.getJSON('@Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(@Url.Action("GetDetails"))', {

            'from': StringToJSONDate(fromdate),
            'to': StringToJSONDate(todate)
        }, function (groupusages) {
           .....Do Something....
            }).error(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            //document.location.href = "/Login";

        });
    });
//function for parsing data to json

  function StringToJSONDate(stringDate) {
    var dateParts = stringDate.split("/");
    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    return date.toJSON();
 }
```

What can i do, where is the problem because it works fine in english and french culture. Please help me!

Comment: Germany uses `.` as the date separator, not `/`. Your inputs will contain a value that looks like `08.07.2015`, when your `StringToJSONDate` function is expecting them to look like `08/07/2015`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to change your method signature to do something like this. You could spend a lot of time working on getting the right format for your mvc app for different cultures.

```
   public JsonResult GetDetails(string from, string to)
        {
           var fromDate = DateTime.Parse(from);
           var toDate = DateTime.Parse(to);
           //Do something..
        }
```

As Khan mentioned in his comment, you could make this a `DateTime.ParseExact()` so that you don't run into other culture issues.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And what string format should i use to pass to the controller?

Comment: @inna Which ever format you choose if you use this solution.  Just make sure you're parsing for this format in the controller.

Comment: @matrixugly A `ParseExact` would make more sense here since `Parse` would only work when the culture matches what the strings match.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact change, but it may be because of a difference in the date/time format that Germany uses versus English and French speaking locations. I would try adding in a few alerts from the javascript to see at various points that you have a value there and then see where it gets screwy. I suspect the value still comes through but is not happy with the date formatting, should be a quick fix with some .split("/") and .join("/") function calls and addressing the index of the array